# Setting CacheProfile in HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, cacheprofile

In an aspx file you can set the CacheProfile to a certain profile defined in Web.Config. How do you do this in a HttpHandler?

I know you can use Cache but can you use Cache Profiles from Web.Config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found is to read the profile from the config and apply it programmatically:

```
var settings = (OutputCacheSettingsSection)
  WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/caching/outputCacheSettings");
var profile = settings.OutputCacheProfiles["ProfileName"];
var cachePolicy = context.Response.Cache;
//Set up your caching here using the profile
cachePolicy.SetExpires(context.Timestamp.AddSeconds(profile.Duration));
//And so on...
```